# Need help on loop in php to sum by group

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, sum

I need some help with below. Need to group my category with amount then with a total sum at the bottom. And calculate the percentage of each category

```
echo print_r($results);

Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
 (
 [expense_category] => Salary
 [expense_amount] => 100
 )
 [1] => stdClass Object
 (
 [expense_category] => Electricity
 [expense_amount] => 30
 )

 [2] => stdClass Object
 (
 [expense_category] => Gas
 [expense_amount] => 15
 )
 [3] => stdClass Object
 (
 [expense_category] => Gas
 [expense_amount] => 10
 )
)
```

I'm trying to get the output below:

```
+--------------------------+--------------+----------+
|Expense Category|cat_count|Expense Amount|Percentage|
+--------------------------+--------------+----------+
|Salary          |1        |100           |65%       |
|Electricity     |1        |30            |19%       |
|Gas             |2        |25            |16%       |
+----------------+---------+--------------+----------+
|TOTAL           |4        |155           |100%      |
+----------------+---------+--------------+----------+
```

Need help below:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Expense Category</th>
  <th>cat_count</th>
  <th>Expense Amount</th>
  <th>Percentage</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $category ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $cat_count ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $amount ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $percent ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>TOTAL</th>
  <th><?php echo $Count_Sum; ?></th>
  <th><?php echo $Cat_Sum; ?></th>
  <th>100%</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And... did you try to write something yourself? Or you looking for someone to do the homework for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, answer is annotated with comments...

```
<?php

$results = [
 "0" => (object)
 array (
 "expense_category" => "Salary",
 "expense_amount" => 100
 ),
 "1" => (object)
 array (
 "expense_category" => "Electricity",
 "expense_amount" => 30
 ),

 "2" => (object)
 array (
 "expense_category" => "Gas",
 "expense_amount" => 15
 ),
 "3" => (object)
 array (
 "expense_category" => "Gas",
 "expense_amount" => 10
 )
];

foreach($results as $object){
    $cat = $object->expense_category;

    // initialize
    // null coalescer ?? requires PHP >= 7
    $cat_count[$cat] = $cat_count[$cat] ?? 0;
    $amount   [$cat] = $amount   [$cat] ?? 0;

    // increment
    $cat_count[$cat]++;

    // sum
    $amount[$cat] += $object->expense_amount;
}

$amount['total'] = array_sum($amount);
// print_r($results);
?>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Expense Category</th>
  <th>cat_count</th>
  <th>Expense Amount</th>
  <th>Percentage</th>
 </tr>
<?php

foreach($cat_count as $cat => $count){
    $percent = $amount[$cat] / $amount['total'];
    $percent = round($percent * 100);
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$cat</td>
            <td>$count</td>
            <td>{$amount[$cat]}</td>
            <td>$percent</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}

?>
 <tr>
  <th>TOTAL</th>
  <th><?php echo array_sum($cat_count); ?></th>
  <th><?php echo $amount['total']; ?></th>
  <th>100%</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Expense Category</th>
  <th>cat_count</th>
  <th>Expense Amount</th>
  <th>Percentage</th>
 </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Salary</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>65</td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
   <td>Electricity</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>30</td>
   <td>19</td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
   <td>Gas</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>25</td>
   <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>TOTAL</th>
  <th>4</th>
  <th>155</th>
  <th>100%</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```